# How capture errorlevel of powershell script in a batch file when execute as admin

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to capture output of powershell script in a batch file when execute as admin.

Example:

**ps1 file:**

```
Write-Host "PS1 executed"
exit 1
```

If I execute powershell script  without admin access

**NotAdminFile.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
endlocal
```

Then, the output is

```
PS1 executed
1
```

This is ok.
But, when I execute powershell script  with admin access

**AdminFile.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dpn0.ps1" ' -Verb RunAs}"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
endlocal
```

Then, the output is:

```
0
```

I don't want that. Can you help me please?

Comment: IMO it **is** OK since the batch errorlevel reflects that powershell ran the Start-Process without errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**exit_1_only.ps1**

```
Write-Host "executed: $($MyInvocation.Line)"
# pause
Exit 123+[int]([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::
    GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]"Administrator")
```

**q44600354.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

(call )
echo errorlevel clear=%errorlevel%

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ^
  "& 'D:\PShell\tests\exit_1_only.ps1'; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
echo errorlevel non-admin=%errorlevel%

echo(
(call )
echo errorlevel clear=%errorlevel%

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ^
  "& {exit ( Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -FilePath PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""D:\PShell\tests\exit_1_only.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE"" ' -Verb RunAs).ExitCode}"
echo errorlevel admin=%errorlevel%
```

**Output**

```
==> D:\bat\SO\q44600354.bat
errorlevel clear=0
executed: & 'D:\PShell\tests\exit_1_only.ps1'; exit $LASTEXITCODE
errorlevel non-admin=123

errorlevel clear=0
errorlevel admin=124

==>
```

**Explanation**

[Exit Codes](https://ss64.com/ps/exit-pssession.html)

> In PowerShell `$?` contains `True` if last operation succeeded and
>   `False` otherwise.
>
> The exit code of the last Win32 executable execution is stored in the
>   automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`
>
> To read exit codes (other than `0` or `1`) launch the PowerShell
>   script and return the `$LASTEXITCODE` in a single line like this:
>
> ```
> powershell.exe -noprofile C:\scripts\script.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE
> ```

[Start-Process](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821638)

> `-PassThru`
>
> Returns a `System.Diagnostics.Process` process object for each process
>   that the cmdlet started. By default, this cmdlet does not generate any
>   output.
>
> `-Wait`
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet waits for the specified process to complete
>   before accepting more input. This parameter suppresses the command
>   prompt or retains the window until the process finishes.

[`(call )`](http://superuser.com/a/649329/376602): Dave Benham in reply to *setting ERRORLEVEL to 0* question:

> If you want to force the `errorlevel` to `0`, then you can use this
>   totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax: `(call )`. The space
>   after *call* is critical. If you want to set the `errorlevel` to `1`,
>   you can use `(call)`. It is critical that there not be any space after
>   *call*.